# Issue with hash url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using url hash to scroll the page. What i am doing is, say i have 2 pages :

`Page1` and `Page2`

First i navigate from `page1` to `page2` and set the url hash than my url will become :

```
 http://localhost:48785/page2#id
```

I am setting hash using this code:

```
window.location.hash = "id";
```

Than i press browser back button and went to previous page i.e. `page1`. Upto this point everythings work fine.

The Issue occure when i set hash twice on page2. Like:

```
 http://localhost:48785/page2#id

 http://localhost:48785/page2#id2
```

Now when i press browser back button, it just navigate back and forth between hash #id and #id2.

Why the back button not taking me to the previous page i.e. page1 after setting hash twice on page2 ?

Comment: That is because these url strings are added to your history. Adding a hash to the url is seen as a new url and therefore added to this history. Consequently it will take you to the last url used. The hash is often used to force this browser history behaviour.

Comment: Issue is when i navigate to page2, than on page2 i change url hash to id, than again i change url hash to id2, now my current url is something like `http://localhost:48785/page2#id2`,now i started pressing back button.On first click i navigate to #id and my url becomes `http://localhost:48785/page2#id`, on second click i excepted to navigate on page1 and my url should be `http://localhost:48785/page1` but it will navigate me on #id2 i.e. `http://localhost:48785/page2#id2`, why?

Comment: Would it suffice to say that it didn't happen :-) .. Got some code? I'll try to set up something, but logic speaks against your claim. I'd love to see it.

Comment: I tried recreating your scenario, but I do not see this behavior in multiple browsers.

Comment: @Daniel I am changing the location hash on `document.ready` event, to scroll to the div whose id equals to hash value'

Comment: Changed my tryout at your request, but nothing like you describe. First hashchange on document.ready, witch causes two entries in the history. After that clicked button to change hash. All follows logic.
My trial can be seen [here](http://77.72.145.127/~danny/page1.php). 
If you have that history, then I would say it is created. Perhaps there is "looping" issue? Can you recreate it in a broken down version?

Answer (score 0):

That's the way the browser back button is supposed to work. It goes back to the last url change in the [browsers history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browsing_history).

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you can use history API like it described here http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/stealing-history-api

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)you can History API and try and remove the history from the browser so that you can get out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Because [HTML5 : 6.6.9 : Navigating to a fragment identifier](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#scroll-to-fragid) says:

> When a user agent is supposed to navigate to a fragment identifier, then the user agent must run the following steps:
>
> 1. Remove all the entries in the browsing context's session history after the current entry. If the current entry is the last entry in the session history, then no entries are removed.
>    This doesn't necessarily have to affect the user agent's user interface.
> 2. Remove any tasks queued by the history traversal task source that are associated with any Document objects in the top-level browsing context's document family.
> 3. **Append a new entry at the end of the History object representing the new resource** and its Document object and related state. Its URL must be set to the address to which the user agent was navigating. The title must be left unset.
> 4. Traverse the history to the new entry, with the asynchronous events flag set. This will scroll to the fragment identifier given in what is now the document's address.

This is done so that links within a document can be backed out of in the same way that links between documents can.  User confusion might result if hitting the back button only served as an undo for some link navigation and not others, especially when scrolling can cause a complete change in the content displayed.